# PHP: How to use DELETE request in curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl in php

how can i use delete request using curl?

this is my code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://192.168.236.44/confbridges/1.json');


curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for DELETE request as:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
```

**[From PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):**

> A custom request method to use instead of "**GET**" or "**HEAD**" when doing a
>   HTTP request. This is useful for doing "**DELETE**" or other, more obscure
>   HTTP requests. Valid values are things like "**GET**", "**POST**", "**CONNECT**"
>   and so on; i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here. For
>   instance, entering "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be
>   incorrect.